# `total_supply` function return value on erc20(psp22)

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, substrate-contracts-node

I am using erc20(psp22) smart contract to create fungible token. Contract successfully compiled and deployed. While I was deploying, I added `initial_supply: Balance as 2`. I tried to read initial_supply from local node in contract ui and display return value of initial supply `2,000,000,000,000` (shown in image).

[image]

Once again I uploaded and added `initial_supply: Balance as 2` in contract ui by using Shuibuya testnet. This time return value of initial supply `2,000,000,000,000,000,000`.

**Why initial_supply is different even though I provided same initial supply while uploading on different testnet?**

[image]

I have tried same in polkadotjs with shibuya testnet instead return value it throws error.

[image]

Someone please explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI will read your contract metadata and if the argument of the method is `Balance` then, by default, it will apply the chain-decimals.
That is why if you input 1 in for a `Balance` field in Shibuya it will actually make the call for 1 + 18 decimals.
If the argument field is an `u128` then this doesn't apply (1 will be 1).

To do so in polkadot js UI for Shibuya chose `atto` (smallest unit): [image]

Also until [this](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538) is not merged, please use our website with the weightV2 fix (you will not get the error you share in the last screen):
https://polkadotjs-apps.web.app/#/explorer