# Out of gas Error for Contract execution

Tags: ink, smart-contract, error

```
    #[ink(message)]
    pub fn dummy_function(
        &mut self,
        value: u64,
    ) -> u64 {
        debug_println!("inside user contract dummy_function");
        return 45 * value;
    }
```

This is my contract function that i was testing on rococo network. This basic txn is giving me `outOfGas` error. What are the possible issues I can have in my contract and how can i resolve them?

Comment: What version of ink!, cargo-contract are you running? If your code fails on local chain too, what is the version of substrate-contracts-node?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of Insufficent Balance (i.e. ROC) in your account. You can get dummy ROC by using [this element link](https://app.element.io/#/room/#rococo-faucet:matrix.org). Just type `!drip "your account key"` and send message you will get `100 ROC`. I have tested in ROCOCO network, haven't faced any issue.

[image]

Comment: I already have funds. Also I tried to execute flipper contract's flip function on rococo and local network. On both network I am getting Out of Gas Error. For get() function I am getting "{ Err: { Module: { index: 7 error: 0x02000000 } } }" error

Comment: I think you have used polkadot.js yes? [as per this response by @P.Ossun](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6711/2844) he stated that weightV2 isn't merged yet. So you can use [this one](https://polkadotjs-apps.web.app/#/explorer). However, I have used [contracts ui](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui)

Comment: use.ink docs now has a convenient webpage getting faucet tokens: https://use.ink/faucet/